# How do I add pages to my AWS static website?

Tags: html, css, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm pretty new to website building, but I've successfully made my homepage (index.html). How do I create additional pages? For example, how do I have about.html become the code for website.com/about or website.com/about.html? I added it to my bucket, so will it just work in time or are there additional steps I must take?

Thanks

[Here is what's in my bucket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHJ5W.png)

Comment: Should work as soon you save the file to your bucket. Does the index.html load when you go to website.com?

Comment: Where are you hosting this website on AWs S3 or AWS EC2 instance?

Comment: I'm hosting with S3. Yes the index loads when i go to website.com but going to website.com/about or website.com/about.html still results in displaying the error page.